# How to navigate spaces in a dual monitor setup?

Tags: macos, spaces, keybindings, dual-screen

I have multiple spaces setup and can navigate them via <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and the arrow keys *left* and *right* on the current active monitor.

Now I want to change to a space that sits on the other monitor.

How do I switch there? I am looking for a keyboard only solution.

Comment: My solution for this was to disable "Displays have separate Spaces" under Mission Control in System . Not an ideal solution, by a long shot, but it is better than reaching for the mouse.

Comment: @JedDaniels Why did you post it as a comment and not as an answer?

Comment: I don't think it is an answer, just a barely functional workaround. I suppose I can put it as an answer if you'd like. I'm still looking for the right AppleScript to do this (which you can then trigger as a keyboard shortcut from the tool of your choice; I use QuickSilver), but I haven't found it yet (I'm no AppleScript junkie).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shell one-liner that will do what you ask:

```
cliclick -r m:=-50,300 w:50 kd:ctrl kp:arrow-left ku:ctrl w:50
```

- [cliclick](https://github.com/BlueM/cliclick) is a tool to move the mouse and is unfortunately necessary for this
- `-r`: When done, move the mouse back to where it was when it started
- `m:=-50,300`: move the mouse to the coordinates (-50, 300). The `=` is to actually do negative x values (for another monitor) rather than relative
- `w:50`: wait 50 milliseconds
- `kd:ctrl`: Press control key
- `kp:arrow-left`: Press and release the left arrow
- `ku:ctrl`: Release control key
- `w:50`: wait 50 milliseconds

(0,0) is the upper left corner of the primary monitor.