# How to change to workspace on non-active monitor?

Tags: macos, ui, dual-screen

I have multiple workspaces. I can switch them via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Arrow Keys Left and Right.

I also have multiple monitor setup. I realized I can only switch this way on the current, active monitor. How do I change the active monitior?

Comment: That awkward moment when you notice that you asked the same question before. http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/132143/53299

Comment: so why are you asking it again ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 By mistake. I want to keep the duplicate though if someone else searches for the same question. Yet somebody should close one as a duplicate.